# What domain registrars provide 'smart' url masked forwarding?

Tags: url, heroku, forwarding

I was hoping to be able to redirect my free (heroku) hosted website to a more pretty address such as www.example.com and still have all sub-url links display in the browser:

For example, when redirecting the following should be the outcome:

`www.example.herokuapp.com` -> redirects to -> `www.example.com`

`www.example.herokuapp.com/blog` -> redirects to -> `www.example.com/blog`

`www.example.herokuapp.com/blog/related` -> redirects to -> `www.example.com/blog/related`

I found it very difficult searching online (since many different buzz words are used to describe masked forwarding) but the bottom most answer in this post is what I'm hoping to find answers on how to implement:
http://www.ozzu.com/mswindows-forum/domain-name-masking-t19301.html

Can anyone provide some direction on how I might set this up (ideally at no extra cost :)

Comment: buy the domain name yourself and change the CNAME record, If your having doubt let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change CNAME record pointing to your heroku app. This is done with your domain registrar, and the process is different from registrar to registrar. Contact support for your registrar, and they will probably be able to assist you.

or below information will help you to get. For more information please go to this link [heroku Custom domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)

After you got the domain name and the domain control panel then follow below

for **custom domain**

```
heroku domains:add www.example.com
```

for **root domain**

```
heroku domains:add example.com
```

Then go to domain control page there you can edit the DNS

change the dns point to `www.example.com or example.com`

You can confirm that your DNS is configured correctly with the host command

```
host www.example.com
```

For example, [here is a step by step tutorial](http://blog.danielebottillo.com/2012/06/heroku-and-gandi-happy-new-website.html) for setting this up with a domain registrar (in this case www.gandi.net) for a heroku app.